# Why does grep hang when run against the / directory?

Tags: sockets, unix, crash, filesystems, grep

My question is in two parts :

1) Why does grep hang when I grep all files under "/" ?

for example :

```
grep -r 'h' ./
```

(note : right before the hang/crash, I note that I see some "no such device or address" messages , regarding sockets....

Of course, I know that grep shouldn't run against a socket, but I would think that since sockets are just files in Unix, it should return a negative result, rather than crashing.

2) Now, my follow up question : In any case -- how can I grep the whole filesystem?  Are there certain *NIX directories which we should leave out when doing this ?  In particular, I'm looking for all recently written log files.

Comment: grep is not hanging, your -r means recursive All files on the system. How many gigabytes is that? Also, any NFS mounted files are being processed at network connection speed, not as a local file on a disk directly connected to your CPU. That will take a long time. Good luck.

Answer (score 20):

As @ninjalj said, if you don't use `-D skip`, `grep` will try to read all your device files, socket files, and FIFO files.  In particular, on a Linux system (and many Unix systems), it will try to read `/dev/zero`, which appears to be infinitely long.

You'll be waiting for a while.

If you're looking for a system log, starting from `/var/log` is probably the best approach.

If you're looking for something that really could be anywhere in your file system, you can do something like this:

```
find / -xdev -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -H pattern
```

The `-xdev` argument to `find` tells it to stay within a single filesystem; this will avoid `/proc` and `/dev` (as well as any mounted filesystems).  `-type f` limits the search to ordinary files.  `-print0` prints the file names separated by null characters rather than newlines; this avoid problems with files having spaces or other funny characters in their names.

`xargs` reads a list of file names (or anything else) on its standard input and invokes the specified command on everything in the list.  The `-0` option works with `find`'s `-print0`.

The `-H` option to `grep` tells it to prefix each match with the file name.  By default, `grep` does this only if there are two or more file names on its command line.  Since `xargs` splits its arguments into batches, it's possible that the last batch will have just one file, which would give you inconsistent results.

Consider using `find ... -name '*.log'` to limit the search to files with names ending in `.log` (assuming your log files have such names), and/or using `grep -I ...` to skip binary files.

Note that all this depends on GNU-specific features.  Some of these options might not be available on MacOS (which is based on BSD) or on other Unix systems.  Consult your local documentation, and consider installing GNU findutils (for `find` and `xargs`) and/or GNU grep.

Before trying any of this, use `df` to see just how big your root filesystem is.  Mine is currently 268 gigabytes; searching all of it would probably take several hours.  A few minutes spent (a) restricting the files you search and (b) making sure the command is correct will be well worth the time you spend.

Comment: This is faster than xargs: `find / -xdev -type f -exec grep -H {} +`.

Answer (score 10):

By default, `grep` tries to read every file. Use `-D skip` to skip device files, socket files and FIFO files.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep seeing error messages, then `grep` is not hanging. Keep `iotop` open in a second window to see how hard your system is working to pull *all* the contents off its storage media into main memory, piece by piece. This operation should be slow, or you have a very barebones system.

> Now, my follow up question : In any case -- how can I grep the whole filesystem? Are there certain *NIX directories which we should leave out when doing this ? In particular, Im looking for all recently written log files.

Grepping the whole FS is very rarely a good idea. Try grepping the directory where the log files should have been written; likely `/var/log`. Even better, if you know anything about the names of the files you're looking for (say, they have the extension `.log`), then do a `find` or `locate` and `grep` the files reported by those programs.

Comment: @jayunit100: http://www.ndchost.com/wiki/server-administration/installing-iotop-centos5